# Creating a swift struct that determines latitude and longitude using CoreLocation

Tags: swift, struct, core-location

How can I create a struct that includes a method to determine latitude and longitude with the [`CoreLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html) framework?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the `CoreLocation` framework, we must import it:

```
import CoreLocation
```

Creating a `struct`... this is pretty basic Swift stuff:

```
struct CLStruct {
    func fetchCoordinates() -> (latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
        // do CoreLocation stuff

    }
}
```

Although what might be more useful is a struct a latitude and longitude property and a method for instantiating one of these structs:

```
struct CLStruct {
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double

    static func structForCurrentPosition() -> CLStruct {
        // do CLStuff to fetch latitude and longitude
        return self(latitude: 37.3318, longitude: -122.0296)
    }
}
```

And we can use it as such:

```
let currentLocation = CLStruct.structForCurrentPosition()
```

---

But with all this said, it's absolutely worth noting that the `CoreLocation` framework has a class called `CLLocation` which already has everything you need for representing a location.  If anything, you probably simple want to extend or subclass this object to add to it whatever you need.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I'm new to Swift abd just cant figure out how to get the coordinates to be sotred on latitude and lo gitude variables, could you please show me an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Create:

```
struct Location {
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
}
```

Instantiate:

```
let myLocation = Location(latitude: 37.331830, longitude: -122.005792)
```

Access:

```
print(myLocation.latitude) // 37.331830
print(myLocation.longitude) // -122.005792
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be recreating the wheel.  Apple already provides a struct for this with a couple helper methods and wider familiarity for other developers.

It is called `CLLocationCoordinate2d`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationcoordinate2d